# Random borders on the right side of an image

Tags: html, css

I have an image that doesn't fit on the screen at 100%:
[100% Size] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCC6w.png)
But does fit at 99%:
[99% Size] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekKt4.png)

This is the code I have used:
Homepage.html

```
<main style="width: 100vw; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
  <img src="Images/HomePageGraphic.png" style="width: 100%; margin-right: 0 !important;">
</main>
```

and General.css

```
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* CSS */
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 238, 208);
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
    display: block;
}
```

[Homepagegraphics.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDgdP.png)
I have tried a CSS reset and setting the margin to 0 with !important. I have also tried setting padding to 0 but that hasn't worked either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet to reproduce?  Normally this is caused by the container element having a natural border.  When I have this problem, I'll usually set the background color to see if I can spot it.

Comment: Provide a sample please. Usual resolution are : add overflow:hidden on the container OR add box-sizing:border-box to the image.

Comment: Also try setting the image to `display:block`.